# Display screenshot after it is taken

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to display a screenCap after it is taken, it is saving the screenCap but how can i get the latest screenCap's url ?

```
local screenCap = display.captureScreen( true )
local alert = native.showAlert( "Success", "Screen Capture Saved to Library", { "OK" } )

NewsScreenShot = display.newImage( "  path to the PNG file  " )
```

Comment: You mean the path to the `PNG` file?

Comment: Yes display.newImage( "  path to the PNG file " )

Answer (score 1):

http://jp.anscamobile.com/dev/reference/index/displaycapturescreen/index.html

The picture will be saved in the device gallery with a name Picture X.png. After this you need to custom selection to the latest indexed picture.

Btw you can try it whit display.save("name",path) and this will be alway the last saved picture.

Comment: path is the path of your app sandbox like : System.DocumentsDirectoy,and after saving the image you can reload from there.

Answer (score 1):

`display.captureBounds` is good for saving the whole screen to the directory. But it usually saves the file with increase in last index. So it may be difficult to read them correctly. So I prefer `display.save`. But it is not a straight way.

For doing this, you have to:

- First create a `displayGroup`.
- Then `add` the screen objects to that group.
- `Return` the display group.
- Use `display.save` to save the entire group displayed.
- Display the desired image from `system.DocumentsDirectory`.

I am giving a sample here:

```
-- creating the display group --
local localGroup = display.newGroup()  

-- creating display objects and adding it to the group --
local bg = display.newRect(0,0,_w,_h)
bg.x = 160
bg.y = 240
bg:setFillColor(150)
localGroup:insert(bg)

local rect = display.newRect(0,0,50,50)
rect.x = 30+math.random(260)
rect.y = 30+math.random(420)
localGroup:insert(rect)

-- Take Screenshot --
local function saveGroupImages()
  -- take screen shot to baseDirectory --
  local baseDir = system.DocumentsDirectory
  display.save( localGroup, "myScreenshot.jpg", baseDir )
end
rect:addEventListener("tap",saveGroupImages)
```

After this, you can read the file and display it as follows:

```
local readImage = display.newImage( "myScreenshot.jpg" ,system.DocumentsDirectory , 50, 100  )
readImage.x = 160
readImage.y = 240
readImage:scale(0.5,0.5)
```

keep Coding........... :)